# PRISM - Xamarin Forms - Disable IsGestureEnable on some Detail page of MasterDetailPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using a Prism library (version 7.2.0.1422) on my Xamarin Forms app.
After user Login I use a `NavigationService.NavigateTo($"/{nameof(MainMasterDetailPage)}/{nameof(MasterDetailNavigationPage)}/{nameof(HomePage)}")` method to set the my "MainMasterDetailPage" as Main Page of App.

**MasterDetailNavigationPage class:**

```
public class MasterDetailNavigationPage : NavigationPage, INavigationPageOptions
{
    public bool ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation => false;
}
```

When the user click to an menu item, I use `NavigationService.NavigateTo("pagename")` method to keep a navigation stack.
In this case the Back Button is present and using a swipe gesture the menu is presented.

In some cases I want that the swipe gesture to open menu is disabled because in some page there is a Gesture Recognizer to manage a swipe gesture in my custom view (to draw again etc).

How I can do this with Prism library? I cant access directly to property "Is Gesture Enabled" present on Master Detail Page.

Comment: Question is unclear, try to be more detailed, if possible showing some code with your attempts

Comment: Thanks for the edit, so you can't do this `Xamarin.Forms.Application.MainPage.IsGestureEnabled = false;` ?

Comment: When you enter your specific page, in her constructor you can write that line and it will achieve what you 're looking for, if I understood your question right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, being SomePage the page where you want to appear this kind of behaviour.

```
class SomePage : ContentPage {

   public SomePage() {
      // Assuming your MasterDetailPage is the root page of the Application
      Xamarin.Forms.Application.MainPage.IsGestureEnabled = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to mark it as the answer then please.

Comment: On `OnDisappearing` I added `Application.MainPage.IsGestureEnabled = true` for enable again the swipe gesture

Comment: Yes nice catch!